# Is there a way to debug css "inside" the browser engine?

Tags: css, webkit

Is there any way to get "into the browser engine" (e.g. webkit on chrome), see how the css declarations are interpreted, and identify errors?

I mean, under "inspect element" you can see in the developer tools which css rules made it to the HTML object. But from that point, if the css itself is wrong, for most of the error there's no way of seeing what is wrong.

For instance: let's say I wrote

"-webkit-animation: fgfdgfdgdf 500ms"

instead of

"-webkit-animation: MyAnimation 500ms"

I would like to get something like an "object fgfdgfdgdf not found" error.

Or, let's say I wrote:

"left: 200px;

position: static;"

The browser will ignore the "left" property because of "position:static". Is there any way I can get some kind of error for the "left" property - something like "property invalid due to static positioning"?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, I believe this comes down to your knowledge. This is a skill and it takes a lot of passion and know-how to get it right.

Here are some benchmarks you can use to guide you.

Taken from - [**http://css-tricks.com/judging-css-spotting-bad-code/**](http://css-tricks.com/judging-css-spotting-bad-code/)

## **The Obvious Test**

Look at the website. If it looks all messed up, then they did a bad job.

Taking that a step further, check it against the browsers you agreed on would be supported. The design should be workable in all of them.

If the design is supposed to be responsive, resize your browser window to ensure the design works no matter what width or height it is.

If everything looks good, that's a good (and required) first step. But it's not absolute proof the CSS is good.

## **The Formatting Test**

Take a look through the authored CSS file. Remember that it's best practice to serve the live website minified CSS (all non-important whitespace removed), so don't look at that.

[image]
*That's not intended to be read by humans. Look at the file that they actually created.*

If you have an established style guide that was expected to be followed, was it followed?

If not, does it look consistent - as if they had a style guide of their own that they adhere to? Or is it a bit sloppy? Sloppy meaning sometimes there is one space after selectors and sometimes there is none. Some blocks of code are indented and others aren't. Single line CSS is mixed with multi-line CSS with no rhyme or reason.

Clean code is the sign of a respectful developer. One who has a respect for the craft and the work they do.

[image]
*If these first two test pass, that's great. But still not quite proof the CSS is good.*

## The Selector Test

Those first two tests could be done by just about anybody, but from here out you'll need to have familiarity with CSS yourself. Start reading the CSS and see if what you're seeing makes sense to you.

## **CSS...**

```
.article #comments ul > li > a.button {
  /* Crazy town */
}
```

**Hope this helps...**